# Unable to find the database file which is "database.s3db"

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, digital-ocean

I am having an issue regarding SQLite DB on Digital Ocean Ubuntu/Debian Server.

Steps I did:

Created headless binaries and uploaded on server.

Started Server through documentation using ./master_server.x86_64 &

I am unable to find the database file which is "database.s3db".

I didn't change the path in SQLite Provider file which is:

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).

Can someone please guide me where I can see the database file. Waiting for your response

Comment: You have to add a code that shows how you are accessing it. You also have to mention where you put the database data in the Editor before building it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: My Problem is strictly Programming and development Related.

everything is working fine on local machine, but not on live server